# What does GotRequestHeaders mean in fiddler?

Tags: ajax, internet-explorer, fiddler

i get problem that the ajax request takes much longer time in IE 11 than in other browser, here i get time line from fiddler. it looks strange that the period between GotRequestHeaders and ClientDoneRequest is really very long.

here my questions:

1.what does GotRequestHeaders mean, I find explanation of other event but not this one?
2.is there anything special in IE 11 for sending ajax request?

ClientConnected: 15:02:28.484
ClientBeginRequest: 15:02:28.501
**GotRequestHeaders: 15:02:28.502**
**ClientDoneRequest: 15:02:31.655**
Determine Gateway: 0ms
DNS Lookup:   1ms
TCP/IP Connect: 0ms
HTTPS Handshake: 0ms
ServerConnected: 15:02:31.657
FiddlerBeginRequest: 15:02:31.657
ServerGotRequest: 15:02:31.657
ServerBeginResponse: 15:02:31.784
GotResponseHeaders: 15:02:31.784
ServerDoneResponse: 15:02:31.784
ClientBeginResponse: 15:02:31.784
ClientDoneResponse: 15:02:31.784

Answer (score 1):

`GotRequestHeaders` means exactly that-- the time at which Fiddler finished reading the request headers from the client. In contrast, `ClientDoneRequest` is the time at which Fiddler finished sending the request body.

Taking 3 seconds to send the body (unless it's a large file upload or something) is indeed unusual. Because of how IE works, the most likely explanation is that there's some JavaScript running that is pegging the CPU for a few seconds which delays the message that causes the POST body content to be transmitted from JavaScript down to the network stack.